# How do you conjugate adjectives that follow a possessive adjective?

Tags: adjective-ending, possessive

If two adjectives are used to describe a noun they both will take the same case.

> Ich habe den guten neuen Film gesehen

If the first of the adjectives is a possessive adjective, what declension does the secondary adjective take? Does the same rule hold true or does the subsequent adjective take the strong/weak declension?

1. > Ich habe dir mein neu Buch geschenken.
2. > Ich habe dir mein neue Buch geschenken.
3. > Ich habe dir mein neues Buch geschenken.

I searched "adjectives following possessive adjectives german" on Google and all I could find were articles talking about how to conjugate the possessive adjective by themselves, which isn't the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It would be the third option, but your verb conjugation is wrong.

This is how it should be:

1. Ich habe den gut**en** neu**en** Film gesehen. (because *Film* is an accusative object)

and then:

3. Ich habe dir mein neu**es** Buch geschen**kt**.

Adjectives are always inflected to match gender, number and case of the noun they refer to, no matter if the are possessive or not.

In this case *Buch* is neuter singular accusative, so both *mein* and *neu* are inflected to match that (*mein* and *neues*).